# How do I debug a DLL used in another program?

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, alteryx

I'm trying to create a .NET framework DLL for a program called Alteryx. I'm following their docs on how to do it, and I can get it working. However, when I try a certain piece of code that references another DLL, it errors.

I'm new to Visual Studio, and I'm not sure how to debug DLLs properly. How can I attach the debugger to Alteryx/the DLL?

Thank you

Comment: Project > Properties > Debug tab, select "Start external program" and type the path to the .exe file.  Breakpoints become active as soon as the program loads your DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think first you need to figure out if the errors from your dll or the external dll. Try to put some try catch and see the exception message and stack trace.

If that is not enough to identify the problem, try to get the source code of the external dll and add it to your solution as referenced project, you could then debug it locally and step into the code.

If that external dll is not a open source project, I used to use a software call reflector from red gate, that would help

https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/